# Extending or Merging root partition remotely

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, remote-access, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-server

I am currently working remotely on a Ubuntu Server, 14.04 LTS.

This is the result of `df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md2         20G   20G     0 100% /
udev             16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  684K  3.2G   1% /run
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             16G     0   16G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/md3        1.8T   68M  1.7T   1% /home
```

As you can see, I have 1.8TB mounted on `/home`, but only 20GB on `/`. This was a mistake, so I would like to merge `/` with `/home`.

Many answers mentioned using `GParted` with a Live CD. However, I cannot do so because I do not have physical access to the server.

The file system is `ext4`. Here is a print out from `parted`, the command line version of gparted.

```
Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name     Flags
 1      20.5kB  1049kB  1029kB                  primary  bios_grub
 2      2097kB  21.0GB  21.0GB  ext4            primary  raid
 3      21.0GB  2000GB  1979GB  ext4            primary  raid
 4      2000GB  2000GB  536MB   linux-swap(v1)  primary
```

**How can I merge or extend `/` using only an ssh terminal?** Is it even possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, I messed up my system while attempting the solution, so I cannot verify whether or not it could have worked. If I can later reproduce this in a VM and confirm it, I will accept the answer. For now, I have upvoted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

What file system is the disk using?  If it's ext4, you might be able to do it with resize2fs:
https://codesilence.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/live-resizing-of-an-ext4-filesytem-on-linux/
Some relevant info:

> You can use fdisk to change your partition table while running. The stock Ubuntu install has created 3 partitions: one primary (sda1), one extended (sda2) with a single logical partition (sda5) in it. The extended partition is simply used for swap, so I could easily move it without losing any data.
>
> - Delete the primary partition
> - Delete the extended partition
> - Create a new primary partition starting at the same sector as the
>     original one just with a bigger size (leave some for swap)
> - Create a new extended partition with a logical partition in it to
>     hold the swap space
>
> Make the file system bigger with resize2fs online on a mounted partition:
>   `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1`
>
> After rebooting the swap space wasn’t active. Turned out you need to run mkswap, adjust /etc/fstab to the new UUID and turn the swap on

The consequences of things going wrong are pretty dire, so if you can find another way to do this, I'd pick that.